# React Router issue with Wildcard

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**Problem**

In the code below, I have a basic Router with several routes ending with a catch-all wildcard. All my routes work in development, but when I host my website on a remote server, my routes will work as I navigate the site via links and break if I refresh or type in a URL to a sub-page. For example, clicking a link that takes me to `/about` works fine, but if I go to `www.mywebsite.com/about` via my browser navigation bar, I experience a 404 error.

**Question**
Why is it that navigating to a sub-page via browser link, or refreshing a sub-page, results in a 404 error?

**Version**

I am using React Router v6.4.4.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Outlet, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import About from './pages/about';
import Contact from './pages/contact';
import Home from './pages/home';
import LeafletMap from './pages/map';
import Property from './pages/property';

const App = () => {
  const HeaderLayout = () => (
    <>
      <header>
        <Navbar />
      </header>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<HeaderLayout />}>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
          <Route path='contact' element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path='property/:propertyId' element={<Property />} />
          <Route path='map' element={<LeafletMap />} />
          <Route path='*' element={<Home />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: If the 404 page is returned by the server, the server needs to be configured to return the index.html from the root, then the app will work on refresh

Comment: See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) for an idea what needs to be configured for various server environment. The general gis is that the server needs to be configured to serve the root index.html file for all page requests. If you share where/how you are deploying the app we may be able to better help.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot/ do not want to change the server configuration, try making use of 'Hash Routing Strategy'. This will add a '#' to your routes and the part of the URL after the Hashtag will not be sent to the server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).